# PowerShell script for cloudwatch custom metric

Tags: powershell

Below is the script i used to monitor and publish logical disk space to cloudwatch, Any one has an idea of of how to amend this scrip to get the memory usage?

```
*enter code here
**#Parameters
$computerName = ""; 
$deviceId = "C:"; 
$instanceId = ""; 

#Send To CloudWatch
$metricName = "EBS Volume Usage";  
$deviceCommand = "DeviceID='" + $deviceId + "'";  
$unit = "Count";  
$disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $computerName -Filter   $deviceCommand | Select-Object Size,FreeSpace;  
$value = (100 - $disk.FreeSpace / $disk.Size * 100);  
Write-Host "Posting Volume Usage To CloudWatch: $($value)";  
aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name $metricName --namespace "Volume   Usage" --value $value --dimensions InstanceId=$instanceId,DeviceID=$deviceId;  
Write-Host "Done";***
```

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It would probably be easier for people to answer this if you added the code as text instead of attaching it as an image. Indent with four spaces to make it a code block.

Answer (score 0):

In the same way you are `Win32_LogicalDisk` for disk info, you can use  `win32_OperatingSystem` to get memory info:

```
#Send To CloudWatch
$metricName = "OS Memory Usage"
$memory = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_OperatingSystem | select TotalVisibleMemorySize,FreePhysicalMemory
$value = ($memory.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $memory.FreePhysicalMemory)  
Write-Host "Posting Memory Usage To CloudWatch: $($value)"
aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name $metricName --namespace "Memory Usage" --value $value --dimensions InstanceId=$instanceId
```

Comment: Managed to figure it out. Thanks a lot